# -webkit-appearance:none style property is not accepted by Firefox browser

Tags: css, webkit, vendor-prefix

I'm working on building new site , i need a drop down menu to select the amount of something in my site . but this drop down menu has a style that i have to make it.
the style of this drop down menu is that the drop down box has no arrow - the arrow that appear on the right to click on it and open the drop down items-.

I have made many searches and I hove found this style property :"-webkit-appearance:none ", in the class of the drop down list ,I have put this property and the arrow has been disappeared using the google chrome browser.

but the "problem" is  : this property is not working on the Firefox browser , the arrow has not been disappeared .

i will give you a simple view to see how this arrow has not been disappeared  in the Firefox browser :

[image: Firefox_view]
here is the chrome view as the drop down menu without the arrow:
[image: chrome_view]

my question is :

is there CSS style property to make a drop down menu without this arrow in the "Firefox" browser ?

Comment: Well, no `-webkit` is the Webkit (Chrome, Safari) vendor-prefix; Firefox uses `-moz`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this property, but vendor prefix of FF is moz, thus -moz-appearance. It might work.

Comment: see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-webkit` prefixed properties are respected by Safari and Chrome only, for Firefox, you need to use `-moz` prefix. When you use `-webkit`, Firefox will just skip the property and will move ahead, thus it spoils your `select` design.

Though, you can achieve the above with a lil hack, wrap your `select` tag using a `div`, assign fix width to your `div`, and than use `greater` `width` for your `select` tag. Now use `background-image` for your select, and use `overflow: hidden;` for the wrapper

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/naBdf/)

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div select {
    width: 220px;
    background-image: url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-basic/256/Download-icon.png);
    background-size: 13px 13px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 180px 5px;
}
```

This way, the above will give you better cross browser compatibility, and you don't have to use `prefixes` as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can try your luck with:

```
-moz-appearance: none
```

But this is a non-standard property..

You can read more about it [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)

Answer (score 1):

for example:

```
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none; 
-moz-appearance: none;
```

but ie still not cover(
Or may be you want to use plagin jquery https://select2.github.io/, but I think, is not very appropriate if you wont castomise only one select.